# Checkout complete with credit card access denied, error while doing payment

Tags: ios, shopify

I have buy code online. While doing payment by shopify app, it's giving me this error:

> checkout complete with credit card access denied

I tried to create channel and store, but no success.

Comment: Have you found any solution?